# How to change display resolution and set permnent in MX Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, resolution, xrandr

I'm using MX Linux now. Usually i'm used to 1152 x 864 resolution, which is not among the default resolutions. So every time when i install a linux os i edit and save the ~/.profile to add xrandr commands as bellow:
in terminal:
`gedit ~/.profile`
in ~/.profile:
`xrandr --newmode "1152x864_60.00"   81.75  1152 1216 1336 1520  864 867 871 897 -hsync +vsymc` 
`xrandr --addmode VGA-1 "1152x864_60.00"`
It always works but now in MX linux every time i am supposed to open display configuration settings and manually set to 1152x864 resolution and also if i open display settings without opening terminal once(just open no command nothing) I could not see the 1152x864 resolution in the list.
(From my understanding i think ~/.profile is not being executed it might be because of auto-login which i enabled for the first time in my Linux machine.)
To be clear what i want is to set 1152x864 as my default resolution.

Edit: As i thought ~/.profile is not being executed in mx linux on login, it is mentioned in [here](https://us-bz3.devzing.com/mx_antix/show_bug.cgi?id=77). So what is the workarounds to execute those command on login

Comment: What is the native resolution of the monitor?  That should be automatically detected.  If you set it to anything else, particularly something other than an even multiple/fraction, you will get interpolation that will seriously degrade sharpness.

Comment: Recommended Resolution by manufacturer: 1366x768(60 Hz) and even that is not listed.By default only 1024x768, 800x600, 848x480, 640x480 are listed in display settings.

Comment: What is the monitor model (and it's a VGA connection?)?  What is the graphics card?  Unless the monitor is ancient, it should communicate its resolution, and that should automatically be set, even if it isn't a common setting.  The fact that this isn't happening suggests that this communication isn't happening.  Also, 1152x864 is a different aspect ratio than 1366x768.  It will give you a distorted display.

Comment: @fixer1234 I'm not saying that changing resolution breaks my display, as you say there is a problem and that is the reason i'm creating a custom resolution.

Comment: And also i'm using this (1152x864) resolution for the past 8 month. To go with the question part i just want to make it permanent instead of changing every time i boot in.

Comment: If you create a custom resolution, the best one to use is 1366x768, since that matches the monitor's native resolution.  But a better fix is to figure out why this isn't happening automatically.  Do you have access to another computer (maybe a friend's), with a VGA output?  You could try connecting the monitor to it to see if it correctly identifies the resolution.  That will narrow down which end of the cable has the problem.  If you have access to another VGA cable, try that.  Sometimes the problem can be a bad cable.  (cont'd)

Comment: Another problem could be the driver.  Open-source graphics drivers are available for the common cards, but Debian is generally a problem with anything proprietary.  You might need to add the non-free repository to access the right or best driver.  If you add the information about your monitor and graphics card models, people will be better able to figure out what the problem is and how to fix it.  You just want to make your workaround permanent, but one reason it isn't permanent is because it isn't fixing the actual problem.

Comment: my monitor: https://ph.aoc.com/upload_files/manual/E2270SWDN/E2270SWDN%20English.pdf and im using intel built in graphics

Comment: *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:29 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93745/discussion-between-sathish-kanna-and-fixer1234).